# Реализация прокрутки всплывающего окна (не его содержимого)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет!
Хочу сделать всплывающее окно по принципу как у Вк, а именно:
если окно появилось, то body стало overflow:hidden и зафиксировалось.
Никак не пойму как сделать чтобы окно прокручивалось (не его содержимое, а само окно) если по высоте оно больше, чем экран браузера юзера. Как такое реализуется? плиз хэлп. Плагины мне подключать не хочется.

```
$('.elem').click(function() {
$('#popup').fadeIn(300);
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам попап должен иметь ширину и высоту окна браузера и иметь свойства `overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;` тогда контент внутри будет скроллиться, если будет выше окна браузера.

Comment: @ MedvedevDev Дак мне не нужно чтобы контент скролился в том тои дело, нужно чтобы скролился сам попап, но не контент. Как у вк.

Comment: Что бы это могло значить .... Я описал ровно то, что сделано в вк (хотя сам от такого отказался, так как медленно работает для большого кол-ва контента). [Собственно стили попапа ВК](https://yadi.sk/i/g5CulXPn3NPccP)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, Распишу подробней: как отследить что высота браузера меньше высоты попапа и если это так, то тогда прокручиваем сам попап?

Comment: Когда у блока задано свойство `overflow: auto` он сам определяет вмещается ли то что внутри него в его размеры, если нет, то добавляет скролл, если вмещается, то не добавляет. Если у попапа `position: fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;`, то он будет иметь размеры окна браузера, а все что внутри будет больше или меньше и это будет давать понять нужен скролл или нет. Там дали ответ, по сути это почти то же самое что сделано в ВК, думаю на этом ответе будет проще понять что именно вам в этом всем не нравится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простой пример попапа, как я понял из вопроса вы именно это хотели.

```js
$('.elem').click(function() {
  $('.popup_container').fadeIn(300);
  $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
});
```

```css
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
}
.popup_container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: none;
  width: 90%; /*Посмотрите на скролл*/
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.elem{
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .popup{
    margin: 5%;
    background: green;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <span> Какой то контент </span>
  <div class="elem"> Click me to open popup window       </div>
  <div class="popup_container">
    <div class="popup">
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
      Какой то большой контент попапа<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ,к сожалению у вас тоже содержимое крутится.

Comment: @МайклМиллер Содержимое чего? в моем случае?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. добавил картинку на которой наглядно видна соль вопроса. В вашем случае скролится контент класса popup

Comment: @МайклМиллер вот изменил ответ, и сейчас наглядно видно что крутится именно та часть что вам нужно, (картинка вопроса).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteProductModalLabel">Заголовок</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Ultra Supercharge - Terms of Offer</h4>

          <p>By placing an order through this website, you agree to the terms and conditions set for the below. Please read through these terms carefully before placing your order and print a copy for future reference. Please also read our Privacy Policy
            regarding personal information provided by you, which is incorporated herein by reference. </p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Health Disclaimer</h4>

          <p>Any statements on this site or any materials or supplements distributed or sold by have not been evaluated by the Food and Drug Administration. This product is not intended to diagnose, treat, cure or prevent any disease.
            If you are pregnant, nursing, taking medication, or have a history of heart conditions we suggest consulting with a physician before using any of our products. The results on all products are not typical and not everyone will experience these
            results. </p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">How Does the Auto-Ship Trial Offer Work?</h4>
          <p>You will receive the product for free; however, you must pay Postage and Packaging of Â£3.50 for us to send you a 14 day trial supply of Ultra Supercharge. We ship the product the day after you place your order (except that orders placed Friday-Sunday
            will be shipped the following Monday). We consider the end date for your trial period to be 14 days after you place your order.</p>

          <p>B. If you do not call customer service to cancel within 14 days of ordering your free trial, you will continue with our auto-ship program. See details below.</p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Auto-Ship Program</h4>

          <p>Unless you cancel before the end of your trial period as specified above, we will ship your first 30-day supply of Ultra Supercharge at the end of your trial period. Thereafter, you will continue to receive a fresh 30-day supply of Ultra Supercharge
            each month for as long as you stay a member of our auto-ship program. The card you provided when you ordered the trial product will be automatically charged Â£79.50 per product ordered when each new product ships. To cancel future shipments
            in the auto-ship program, you must call  at least 1 day prior to the date that your next monthly delivery ships. Our customer service centre open Monday to Friday 8am-4pm.</p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Ultra Supercharge Guarantee:</h4>
          <p>Return Policy for Auto-Ship Deliveries</p>

          <p>Ultra Supercharge retains a total guarantee of customer satisfaction on all Ultra Supercharge auto-ship products. If you, the buyer, are unhappy with the product for any reason â€” even if you've used the full supply of the supplementâ€” you
            can return the empty bottle for a full refund of the purchase price minus shipping and handling. To obtain your refund, you must do the following: Call us at  hours a day. You will be given a Return Merchandise Authorisation
            (RMA) number. To receive your refund, your return must be received at our shipping facility within 30 days of purchase. Be sure to clearly write the return merchandise authorisation (RMA) number on the outside of the box. Our shipping department
            is NOT allowed to accept any packages without an RMA number. You pay for return delivery costs. </p>

          <p>Address the return package to: BNE Bio Natural Essentials, F. We will not accept or issue a refund for any packages marked return to sender or refused that do not include a valid RMA number. If you return a
            package, we recommend that you get proof of shipment. Upon receipt of your returned product with a valid RMA number, a refund will be issued to your credit or debit card. After the shipping department receives your return, it generally takes
            3-5 business days or less to process your refund. Once a return is processed, it can take up to one billing cycle for this return to be posted to your account, depending on your bank. </p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">TERMS OF SERVICE</h4>

          <p>This Terms of Service ("TOS") is a legally binding agreement made by and between BNE Bio Natural Essentials Ltd ("we" or "us") and you, personally and, if applicable, on behalf of the entity for whom you are using this web site (collectively,
            "you"). This TOS governs your use of the UltraMuscleBoost.com web site ("Web Site") and the services we offer on the Web Site ("Services"), so please read it carefully. BY ACCESSING OR USING ANY PART OF THE WEB SITE, YOU AGREE THAT YOU HAVE
            READ, UNDERSTAND AND AGREE TO BE BOUND BY THIS TOS. IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO BE SO BOUND, DO NOT ACCESS OR USE THE WEB SITE. INTERNET TECHNOLOGY AND THE APPLICABLE LAWS, RULES, AND REGULATIONS CHANGE FREQUENTLY. ACCORDINGLY, WE RESERVE THE RIGHT
            TO MAKE CHANGES TO THIS TOS AT ANY TIME. YOUR CONTINUED USE OF THE WEB SITE CONSTITUTES ASSENT TO ANY NEW OR MODIFIED PROVISION OF THIS TOS THAT MAY BE POSTED ON THE WEB SITE. </p>


          <h4 class="modal-title">Information and Content </h4>
          <p>Copyright- All material present on UltraMuscleBoost.com, whether text, video, audio, or any other form is subject to intellectual property rights such as copyright, trademark and other property rights. This material is property of the respected
            owners. All rights are expressly reserved. Reproducing, copying, manipulating, or using this information without the prior written consent of the legal owner of such material could result in civil or criminal prosecution. </p>


          <p>Personal Use- UltraMuscleBoost.com is designed for personal, non-commercial use. We would like to inform you that using any material or information from our site for any non-personal purpose could be considered illegal and may result in criminal
            or civil prosecution. UltraMuscleBoost.com will not be held responsible in the event that you encounter material that you deem offensive, indecent or otherwise objectionable. </p>


          <p>Errors, Mistakes and Missing Information- Despite our tireless efforts, UltraMuscleBoost.com cannot guarantee that our website will be completely free of errors and misleading information. In the event of an error or other content related issue,
            UltraMuscleBoost.com reserves the right to correct such error without notification. UltraMuscleBoost.com also reserves the right to cancel any order that may have been made under the pretense of such error. In the event where an order is cancelled,
            but has been paid for, the user will receive a full refund. </p>


          <p>Customer Feedback- Please note that all customer feedback given to UltraMuscleBoost.com shall be considered the property of UltraMuscleBoost.com. This includes all customer communication, testimonials and contact information. By releasing this
            information to UltraMuscleBoost.com, you are hereby giving UltraMuscleBoost.com the non-exclusive, worldwide, perpetual, irrevocable, royalty-free, and unlimited right to reproduce, modify, publish, translate and distribute such material in
            any way deemed appropriate by the management of UltraMuscleBoost.com.</p>

          <p>Shopping-Product Use will be calculated based on the laws of the jurisdiction in which the product is scheduled to be delivered. Use by Minors-To purchase a product from UltraMuscleBoost.com you must be the legal age of majority as stated by
            the law of the jurisdiction in which you reside. </p>


          <p>Payment Agreement- By purchasing a product from UltraMuscleBoost.com you are agreeing to pay any and all charges associated with the purchased product. Shopping Limitations- UltraMuscleBoost.com reserves the right to limit quantities products.
            UltraMuscleBoost.com also reserves the right to eliminate products from our website, cancel orders or prohibit access to certain pages at any time. </p>

          <p></p>Product Us- UltraMuscleBoost.com shall not be held liable for any damages resulting from the misuse of any product. Therefore, it is the sole responsibility of the customer to read all product instructions carefully, to use the product strictly
          for the purpose it was designed for, and to ensure that the product is used in a safe and reasonable manner. UltraMuscleBoost.com shall not be held responsible for any damages that occur due to an allergic reaction, or as the result of any other
          unforeseen occurrence.</p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Website Operations </h4>
          Website Safety- UltraMuscleBoost.com or any affiliated party is not responsible for any damages, either in contract, warranty, tort (including passive or imputed negligence), product liability, strict liability or other theory, that may result from the
          use of our website. </p>

          <p>Service Availability- Please note that the services provided by UltraMuscleBoost.com are available only on an as is and as available basis. UltraMuscleBoost.com is not responsible for any and all losses, whether direct or indirect, exceeding
            the price of the goods purchased. </p>

          <p>Outbound Links- UltraMuscleBoost.com may link to websites outside the control of UltraMuscleBoost.com. Please understand that a link should be in no way considered an endorsement of a website. UltraMuscleBoost.com cannot be held liable under
            any circumstances for any damages that may occur as a result of a user visiting a page through an outbound link. Unlawful Use- It is illegal to use UltraMuscleBoost.com for any illegal or destructive purpose. This includes any use of the website
            that could result in damaging, disabling, overloading or in any other way compromising the website. Accessing or attempting to access information not intentionally made available to you is illegal and may result in civil or criminal prosecution.
            </p>

          <h4 class="modal-title">User's Rights and Responsibilities</h4>

          <p>Identification- Misrepresenting your identity while using UltraMuscleBoost.com will be considered a clear violation of our terms of service and may result in you being banned from the website and possibly civil or criminal prosecution.</p>

          <p>User Responsibility- As a user UltraMuscleBoost.com, you are responsible for any monetary charges resulting from your use of the site. These fees include any claim, cause of action, demand, including but not limited to, legal, accounting and
            any other fees that result from the use of the website. User Right to Termination- You must agree to these terms of service in order to use UltraMuscleBoost.com. If you cannot or decide you do not want to agree with the Terms of Services displayed
            on this page, you are prohibited from using this website and should leave UltraMuscleBoost.com immediately. Legal Stuff Precedence- These terms of service in combination with our Privacy Policy represent a legally binding agreement between
            the user and UltraMuscleBoost.com. This agreement shall replace all prior oral and/or written communication between the user and UltraMuscleBoost.com. If a conflict is to occur between a previous, present or future agreement and the above
            terms of service, the terms of service will have precedence, unless clearly noted in the prior agreement.</p>

          <p>Severability- In the event that one or more of the provisions of UltraMuscleBoost.com's terms of service is regarded as unenforceable, the remaining provisions will continue to be in place and enforced to the greatest extent of the law. </p>

          <p>Fraud- We reserve the right, but undertake no obligation, to actively report and prosecute actual and suspected credit card fraud. We may, in our discretion, require further authorization from you such as a telephone confirmation of your order
            and other information. We reserve the right to cancel, delay, refuse to ship, or recall from the shipper any order if fraud is suspected. We capture certain information during the order process, including time, date, IP address, and other
            information that will be used to locate and identify individuals committing fraud. If any Web Site order is suspected to be fraudulent, we reserve the right, but undertake no obligation, to submit all records, with or without a subpoena, to
            all law enforcement agencies and to the credit card company for fraud investigation. We reserve the right to cooperate with authorities to prosecute offenders to the fullest extent of the law. </p>

          <p>Indemnification- You agree to defend, indemnify and hold the Web Site, and its subsidiaries, affiliates, and their directors, officers, agents, members, shareholders, co-branders or other partners, employees, and Ad Partners harmless from any
            liabilities, losses, actions, damages, claims or demands, including reasonable attorneysâ€™ fees, costs and expenses, made by any third party directly or indirectly relating to or arising out of (a) content you provide to the Web Site or otherwise
            transmit or obtain through the Service, (b) your use of the Service, (c) your connection to the Service, (d) your violation of this Agreement, (e) your violation of any rights of another or (f) your failure to perform your obligations hereunder.
            If you are obligated to provide indemnification pursuant to this provision, we may, in our sole and absolute discretion, control the disposition of any Claim at your sole cost and expense. Without limitation of the foregoing, you may not settle,
            compromise or in any other manner dispose of any Claim without our consent. DISCLAIMERS, EXCLUSIONS AND LIMITATIONS. (a) DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTIES. WE PROVIDE THE WEB SITE, THE PRODUCTS, AND SERVICESON AN â€œAS IS AND â€œAS AVAILABLE BASIS.
            WE DO NOT REPRESENT OR WARRANT THAT THE PRODUCTS, THE WEB SITE, THE SERVICES, ITS USE, ANY INFORMATION ON IT: (I) WILL BE UNINTERRUPTED OR SECURE, (II) WILL BE FREE OF DEFECTS, INACCURACIES OR ERRORS, (III) WILL MEET YOUR REQUIREMENTS, OR
            (IV) WILL OPERATE IN THE CONFIGURATION OR WITH OTHER HARDWARE OR SOFTWARE YOU USE. WE MAKE NO WARRANTIES OTHER THAN THOSE MADE EXPRESSLY IN THIS TOS, AND HEREBY DISCLAIM ANY AND ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, WARRANTIES
            OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, MERCHANTABILITY AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. (b) DISCLAIMER OF FORWARD-LOOKING STATEMENTS. THIS WEB SITE MAY CONTAIN FORWARD-LOOKING STATEMENTS THAT REFLECT OUR CURRENT EXPECTATION REGARDING FUTURE EVENTS AND
            BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT. THE FORWARD-LOOKING STATEMENTS INVOLVE RISKS AND UNCERTAINTIES. ACTUAL DEVELOPMENTS OR RESULTS COULD DIFFER MATERIALLY FROM THOSE PROJECTED AND DEPEND ON A NUMBER OF FACTORS, SOME OF WHICH ARE OUTSIDE OUR CONTROL. (c)
            HEALTH RELATED INFORMATION. WE PROVIDE INFORMATION ON THE WEB SITE FOR INFORMATIONAL PURPOSES ONLY. IT IS NOT MEANT AS A SUBSTITUTE FOR THE ADVICE OF A DOCTOR OR OTHER HEALTH CARE PROFESSIONAL. YOU SHOULD NOT USE THE INFORMATION AVAILABLE
            ON OR THROUGH THE WEB SITE FOR DIAGNOSING OR TREATING A MEDICAL CONDITION. YOU SHOULD CAREFULLY READ ALL PRODUCT INSTRUCTIONS PRIOR TO USE. (d) PRODUCTS. ALL PRODUCTS ARE SUBJECT ONLY TO ANY APPLICABLE WARRANTIES OF THEIR RESPECTIVE MANUFACTURERS,
            DISTRIBUTORS, AND SUPPLIERS, IF ANY, PROVIDED IN THE PRODUCT PACKAGING. TO THE FULLEST EXTENT PERMISSIBLE BY APPLICABLE LAW, WE HEREBY DISCLAIM ALL WARRANTIES OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY IMPLIED
            WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, NON-INFRINGEMENT, OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. WITHOUT LIMITING THE GENERALITY OF THE FOREGOING, WE HEREBY EXPRESSLY DISCLAIM ALL LIABILITY FOR PRODUCT DEFECT OR FAILURE, CLAIMS THAT ARE DUE TO NORMAL
            WEAR, PRODUCT MISUSE, ABUSE, PRODUCT MODIFICATION, IMPROPER PRODUCT SELECTION, NON-COMPLIANCE WITH ANY CODES, OR MISAPPROPRIATION. (e) EXCLUSION OF DAMAGES. WE WILL NOT BE LIABLE TO YOU OR ANY THIRD PARTY FOR ANY CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL,
            INDIRECT, PUNITIVE OR SPECIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, WITHOUT LIMITATION, DAMAGES RELATING TO LOST PROFITS, LOST DATA OR LOSS OF GOODWILL) ARISING OUT OF, RELATING TO OR CONNECTED WITH THE USE OF THE WEB SITE OR PRODUCTS, REGARDLESS OF THE CAUSE
            OF ACTION ON WHICH THEY ARE BASED, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES OCCURRING. (f) LIMITATION OF LIABILITY. IN NO EVENT WILL OUR AGGREGATE LIABILITY ARISING FROM, RELATING TO, OR IN CONNECTION WITH THIS TOS (INCLUDING, WITHOUT
            LIMITATION, CLAIMS RELATING TO THE WEB SITE, OR THE PRODUCTS) EXCEED THE GREATER OF $100 OR THE AMOUNT THAT YOU PAID FOR THE PRODUCTS. </p>



          <p>Force Majeure- You acknowledge and understand that if the Web Site is unable to provide the Products as a result of a force majeure event the Website will not be in breach of any of its obligations towards You under these Terms of Service. A
            force majeure event means any event beyond the control of the Website. THE WEBSITE SHALL NOT HAVE ANY LIABILITY TO YOU WHETHER IN CONTRACT, WARRANTY, TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE), OR ANY OTHER FORM OF LIABILITY FOR FAILING TO PERFORM ITS OBLIGATIONS
            UNDER THIS AGREEMENT TO THE EXTENT THAT SUCH FAILURE IS AS A RESULT OF A FORCE MAJEURE EVENT. WAIVER OF CLASS ACTION RIGHTS. BY ENTERING INTO THIS TOS, YOU HEREBY IRREVOCABLY WAIVE ANY RIGHT YOU MAY HAVE TO JOIN CLAIMS WITH THOSE OF OTHERS
            IN THE FORM OF A CLASS ACTION OR SIMILAR PROCEDURAL DEVICE. ANY CLAIMS ARISING OUT OF, RELATING TO, OR CONNECTED WITH THIS TOS MUST BE ASSERTED INDIVIDUALLY. </p>

          <p>Limitation of Actions- You acknowledge and agree that, regardless of any statute or law to the contrary, any claim or cause of action you may have arising out of, relating to, or connected with your use of the Web Site, must be filed within
            one calendar year after such claim or cause of action arises, or forever be barred. </p>

          <p>Modification of Terms of Service- We reserve the right to change or modify these Terms of Use at any time and your continued use of this site will be conditioned upon the Terms of Use in force at the time of your use. You can always check the
            most current version of the Terms of Use at this page.</p>


          <p>Termination- We will have the right to terminate your access to the Web Site if we reasonably believe you have breached any of the terms and conditions of this TOS. Following termination, you will not be permitted to use the Web Site and we
            may, in our discretion, cancel any outstanding Product Orders. If your access to the Web Site is terminated, we reserve the right to exercise whatever means we deem necessary to prevent unauthorized access to the Web Site, including, but not
            limited to, technological barriers, IP mapping, and direct contact with your Internet Service Provider. This TOS will survive indefinitely unless and until we choose to terminate it, regardless of whether any account you open is terminated
            by you or us or if you have the right to access or use the Web Site. Integration. This TOS contains the entire understanding between you and us regarding the use of the Web Site, and supersedes all prior and contemporaneous agreements and
            understandings between you and us relating thereto. </p>

          <p>Please feel free to contact us, if you have any questions regarding our terms of service. </p>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">ok</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteProductModal" data-productid="3" data-productname="Product 3">Delete</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Вот превосходное решение, реализованное на Bootstrap, сам долго искал, авось кому поможет)